# How to I avoid E042 local declaration hides errors with bashate?

Tags: bash, bashate

Bashate linter throws an error when you use local but it gives no indicarion on how to rewrite the code to make it pass the linting.

Obviously that I could disable that check but that not the point, the idea is to find a way to write the code in a better way.

Example from https://github.com/openstack/kolla-ansible/blob/master/tools/kolla-ansible#L6

```sh
function find_base_dir {
    local real_path=$(python -c "import os;print(os.path.realpath('$0'))")
    local dir_name="$(dirname "$real_path")"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, all it takes to placate `bashate` in this case is separation of the variable declaration from the subshell capture:

```
function func {
    local var
    var="$(...)"
    ...
}
```

This way you can check for errors that might have occured in the subshell:

```
var="$(...)"
status=$?
```

Initially I thought `bashate` may have complained because the status var `$?` was not handled, or that there might exist a method of capturing subshell output that I was not aware of. It was not, and I was not. Some related points however:

`$?` can be captured in an atomic expression:

```
output=$(inner) || exit $?
```

see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/363454/946541) by @grawity for similar forms.

`$?` reports the status of the `local` command rather than the subshell's exit status if used in a composite expression:

```
f() { local    v=$(echo data; false); echo output:$v, status:$?; }
g() { local v; v=$(echo data; false); echo output:$v, status:$?; }
```

```
$ f     # fooled by 'local' with inline initialization
output:data, status:0
$ g     # a good one
output:data, status:1
```

see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1103711/946541) by @ryenus for more information.

Finally, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443514/312094) among others in the thread detail some deficiencies in terms of portability and the style `bashate` prescribes, which reinforces the notion that style guides are just tools that may or may not be the right tool for the job.